# inputbox takes up 100% screen width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just got started with bootstrap on a home server using IIS and visual studio 2015, I created a top nav bar using bootstrap that has a search input box, everything looks fine apart from this input box seems to take up the whole width of the browser screen and therefore is forced on it a new line by itself. Any solutions?

this is the header info:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

this is inside the body:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      &nbsp;<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Tradesman</a></div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are working with (HTML/CSS/JS) in a minimal, working example Snippet. [mcve]

Comment: The only time the input will be 100% width is under 768px. What width are you trying to reduce it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the width using custom CSS:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      &nbsp;<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Tradesman</a></div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control{
    width:50%;
}
```

Fiddle:[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/7qvvp2tj/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look before you start.
[LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)